# validation loss is increasing and validation acc. is increasing and val_acc stops after 10-15 epoch

Tags: python, keras, training-data, loss-function

I have tried to train my network using image datasets. 
The network includes 5 conv. layer and 2 output layer. I merged the datasets as one dataset for the input of my network.
While the training step, train accuracy is increasing and training loss is decreasing well. However, validation accuracy is increasing, the validation loss is increasing, too. How can I solve the problem?

I changed the learning rate, batch size, or the ratio of train test split... But nothing changed.

Comment: are you using softmax with cross entropy ? if yes, then reason could be higher probabilities for all classes which is making it look like accuracy and loss both are increasing with every epoch

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I am using softmax and cross entropy. Yes, It could be.